# Задача с циклом python

Tags: python

[image: Задача]

Мне кажется я что-то упустил или всё верно?

```
for i in range(2,30,2):
    c=1-(1/i)
c*=c
print(c)
#Вывод 0.9298469387755103
```

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, **конкретную проблему или ошибку** и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе. **Вопросы без явного описания проблемы бесполезны для остальных посетителей.**

Comment: упустил кое-что, да

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Упустили.

- вы производите умножение один раз, после цикла.
- range не включает свой stop аргумент

Должно быть что-то вроде этого:

```
c = 1
for i in range(2,31,2):
    c *= 1-(1/i)

print(c)
```